# How do I add pictures from my assets folder to my React Application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web-applications, react-router

I'm currently building an e-commerce site and I'm having trouble showing my images inside of my react app.

My Components is called "Products" where I created a file called "Products.jsx" Inside of this file, I'm creating an array with my products list:

```
const products = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Macbook-Slim', description: 'Apple Computer 13', price: '$500.00', image: '../../assets/furtniture1.jpg'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Macbook-Pro', description: 'Apple Computer 16', price: '$1200.00', image: '../../assets/furtniture2.jpg'}, 
]
```

For the same reason, I'm calling these products inside of my "Product.jsx"

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
    const classes =useStyles();


    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
                <CardMedia className={classes.media} image='product.image' title={product.name} />
                <CardContent>
                    <div className={classes.cardContent}>
                        <Typography variant="h5" gutterBottom>
                            {product.name}
                        </Typography>
                        <Typography variant="h5">
                            {product.price}
                        </Typography>
                    </div>
                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">{product.description}</Typography>
                </CardContent>
                <CardActions disableSpacing className={classes.cardActions}>
                    <IconButton aria-label="Add to Cart">
                        <AddShoppingCart />
                    </IconButton>

                </CardActions>
            </Card>
    )
}
```

To render these components, I used my app.js file to make sure they will appear in the Front-End.

```
import React  from 'react';
//import Products from './components/Products/Products';
//import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';

import { Products, Navbar } from './components';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Products />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

However, my images are not appearing, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Also, you can take a look at my (repo)[https://github.com/hvaandres/Ecommerce_Shopping_Stripe]

Comment: Try removing `image='product.image'` per `image={product.image}`. I think you are passing to the `image` prop just a string, not your image.

Comment: Fix the above and move the image assets to the public folder so they are available when your app is running and being served up. Otherwise you will need to process and import them *into* your app as Jackob indicates below. https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-yalow-63gep?file=/src/components/Products/Product/Product.jsx

Answer (score 0):

To add pictures, first you need to import them at the top.

```
import YourImage from "../assets/YouImage.png";
```

After that you can use it in a img Tag like this:

```
<img src={YourImage}></img>
```